# opkg failed to install ipk package

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi2, buildroot, opkg

I have created an image with buildroot for raspberry pi 2 and i have included "Opkg" in it. I then manually downloaded "gcc_4.8.3-1_brcm2708.ipk" for it and moved this file into the SD card and logged in to the pi, but now when i run the command "opkg install gcc_4.8.3-1_brcm2708.ipk" , i get the following error:

```
 * open_outer: Failed to open package 'gcc_4.8.3-1_brcm2708.ipk': Unrecognized archive format
 * pkg_extract_control_file_to_stream: Failed to extract control.tar.gz from package 'gcc_4.8.3.
 * pkg_init_from_file: Failed to extract control file from gcc_4.8.3-1_brcm2708.ipk.
```

Is there a problem with the package or the image or it is something else?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation of the project, especially http://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-binary-packages, which tells you that Buildroot does not support generating binary packages.

Plus, you cannot take some random .ipk found on the Internet, and expect it to work on a random Buildroot generated system. How can you be sure it's generated for the right architecture, with the same C library, the same ABI, etc.

Comment: Yeah I got to the conclusion that what you said in the first part of your answer is true; But note that this is not a random .ipk and random system. I have downloaded it for the same architecture of raspberry pi 2 that you can see from the name of the file.

Comment: Being for the same architecture is not sufficient. It should be the same C library (and a version that is compatible: uClibc versions are not ABI compatible with each other), and the ABI used should be the same.